# Question with a branch of logarithm and argument

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration

[image]

This is an example from Stein book. Here I can't understand why the last equation holds. Isn't it supposed to be $-i$ instead of just $i$, because the exponent is $-1/2$.

Also, the given integral is known to be inverse of $sin z$ where $H$ is the upper half plane. Could anyone please show me how to prove this fact?